# How to check if a contourArea() is inside a circle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm making something that should be able to do, things if it detects that the area gotten from
the contourArea function is inside a circle
which i was able to detect using the HoughCircles function
so i have a list of circles from the HoughCircles
and what i want to do is
loop over those circles to check if the output of contourArea is inside any of them
i cant seem to figure out how to do the checking part

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick first pass, test if contour bounding box is inside/intersects with any of the circle bounding boxes. Test the vertices of the contour or its bounding box against the bounding boxes of the circles. Anything that passes will need to test each vertex of the contour against each circle.

Comment: A point is inside a circle if (X-Xc)^2 + (Y-Yc)^2 < R. Where Xc,Yc is the enter and R is the radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out
i used boundingRect() on the contour and got the x,y from it (the center of the rectangle)
then i got the x,y and the radius of the circle and calculated the distance between x,y and the circle's x,y then if that distance is equal to or less than the radius then its inside that circle if not then its not

```
def isInside(circle_x, circle_y, rad, x, y):
    if ((x - circle_x) * (x - circle_x) + (y - circle_y) * (y - circle_y) <= rad * rad):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Cant the contour reach out of the circle! Is checking the center enough? Imagine a curve that surrounds half of your circle but is completely outside. The center of the boundingRect of that curve will be inside the circle.

Comment: @Micka what we are checking is if the entire contour is inside the diameter of the circle